# Big O - Nested For Loop Breakdown Loop by Loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I understand how to get a general picture of the big O of a nested loop, but what would be the operations for each loop in a nested for loop?

If we have:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<1000; j++)
    {
        do something of constant time;
    }
}
```

How exactly would we get T(N)? The outer for loop would be n operations, the inner would be 1000(n-1) and the inside would just be c is that right?

So `T(n)=cn(1000(n-1))` is that right?

Comment: handle the two loops together - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: "do something" will run till  n = 999. so O(1) is the time complexity

Answer (score 0):

You want to collapse the loops and do a double summation.  When *i* = 0, you run 1000-1 times.  When *i* = 1, you run 1000 - 2 times, and so on up to *n-1*.  This is equivalent to the sum from *i* = 0 to *n* of the series 999 - *i*, Note that you can separate the terms and get 999 *n* - *n* (*n* - 1)/2.

This is a pretty strange formula, because once *n* hits 1,000, the inner loop immediately short-circuits and does nothing.  In this case, then, the asymptotic time complexity is actually O(*n*), because for high values of *n*, the code will just skip the inner loop in constant time.

Comment: I just asked my professor. As @Zap said it is O(1), not linear, because the inner loop will only be executed when n is less than 1000, so for big n (ex: 1,001 and 100,000,000) it will be the same. It might be linear till 1000, but it is constant after that....

Comment: It’s only constant in the number of inner-loop invocations.  That’s ignoring the cost of comparing *i*+1 to 1,000 once per outer loop, which makes the time complexity linear.